# How to fix the below LinQ Cartesian program and make it working?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, cartesian-product

I am trying to have the below program working in order to generate cartesian product of n lists. However I am not able to compile it successfully.

```
namespace CombiGenerator
{
    static class AppendExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that, T item)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> itemAsSequence = new T[] { item };
            return that.Concat(itemAsSequence);
        }
    }


    public static class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            object[] letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
            object[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            object[] colours = { "Red", "Blue" };

            var cartesianProduct = CartesianProduct(letters, numbers, colours);
            foreach (var item in cartesianProduct)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item));
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> inputs)
        {
            return inputs.Aggregate(
                EnumerableFrom(Enumerable.Empty<T>()),
                (soFar, input) =>
                    from prevProductItem in soFar
                    from item in input
                    select prevProductItem.Append(item));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> EnumerableFrom<T>(T item)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'CartesianProduct' takes 3 arguments  
c:\users\hp 15\documents\visual studio  2013\Projects\CombiGenerator\CombiGenerator\Program.cs  30  36  CombiGenerator
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You've defined the method to take in a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, yet when you call it you're passing in three `object[]`

Comment: @RufusL - The extension is actually made to allow different sized objects.I am actually trying to make the program work from the below link : http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/08/02/linq-cartesian-4

Comment: `var cartesianProduct = CartesianProduct(new[] {letters, numbers, colours});` - You needed to pass in an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` which you can do by making an array of arrays of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the following line:

```
var cartesianProduct = CartesianProduct(letters, numbers, colours);
```

letters, numbers, and colours need to be stuffed into an IEnumerable and then passed into CartesianProduct.

Note: I default to Lists in examples when writing new code:

```
object[] letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
object[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
object[] colours = { "Red", "Blue" };

List<object[]> cartesianProducts = new List<object[]> { letters, numbers, colours };
var cartesianProduct = CartesianProduct(cartesianProducts);
```

You need to pass in an IEnumerable of IEnumerables (**List of arrays of objects in my example**) but you are just trying to pass in three separate IEnumerables (**Arrays of objects in your example**)